# creating a new instance of an object and putting it in an array with a button on a TabBarView with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am just trying to create a tab bar view that has a button on it that creates an instance of an object and then adds it to an array. I got it working with just the one viewcontroller, but for some reason when I add a tab bar controller I cannot for the life of me get it to work. right now it is throwing this error -  fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is all the code that I have at this moment across a few different files

```
class ItemStore {

    var allItems = [Item]()



    @discardableResult func createItem() -> Item {
        let newItem = Item(name: "Item")

        allItems.append(newItem)

        return newItem
    }
}
```

that's the item and then creates and adds it to the array

here is my main view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var itemStore: ItemStore

    required init?() {
    }


    @IBAction func testButton(_ sender: Any) {

        print("This is working")
        itemStore.createItem() //this is where the error gets thrown
        print("We made it")

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        print("is this coming up")


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

and then this is what I have in the app delegate that has gotten me this far

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var itemStore = ItemStore()


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let tabController = window?.rootViewController as? ViewController
    tabController?.itemStore = itemStore

    return true
}
```

I do have a file for the UITabController.. but it's sitting empty right now. I have tried all kinds of things and I suppose I just don't get it yet.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In `AppDelegate`, update `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`  as this `if let tabController = window?.rootViewController as? ViewController {
    tabController.itemStore = itemStore }` and verify if you are able to assign the `itemStore` to `tabController`

Comment: it let me do that, but it still throws the same error.

Comment: did you verify that is went inside the if condition and itemStore is assigned?

Comment: I added the closure and the if statement at the beginning of that line just as you typed it above. It did not throw an error until the app loaded and I clicked the button. Then it gave me the same error as I wrote above.

Comment: A quick fix to your crash is to make `itemStore` in `ViewController` optional as `var itemStore: ItemStore?` and update the calling as `itemStore?.createItem()`

Comment: This will fix the issue but you will pull your hair on finding why the items are not creating.

Comment: try writing `var itemStore = ItemStore()` in `didFinishLaunching` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above mentioned error occurs when you try to **force-unwrap** an optional variable but the value is not present (nil). Try this approach.

---

Make itemStore an optional variable inside your `ViewController`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var itemStore: ItemStore?
}
```

---

And write this line

```
var itemStore = ItemStore()
```

**Inside** didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and modify the function like below

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    var itemStore = ItemStore()

    if let tabController = window?.rootViewController as? ViewController {
      //MAKE SURE THAT THIS `IF` condition is satisfied by putting a break point here
      tabController.itemStore = itemStore
    }


    return true
}
```

And your function should be like this

```
@IBAction func testButton(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let itemStore = itemStore else {
     //item store is nil. probably not initialized properly from appDelegate.
     return //be safe
    }
    //itemStore is not nil
    itemStore.createItem() //now error will not be thrown
    print("We made it")

}
```

Do let me know if you need any help

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `ItemStore` object is initialized.

declare your ItemStore with below in your `ViewController` :

```
var itemStore: ItemStore!
```

Comment: I added that and still getting the same error - what exactly do you mean it is initialized?

Comment: In your ViewContoller, you might get it as nil so it's crashing. So with "!" operator you will have not nil value.

Comment: @iOSTeam its a bad idea to forcefully unwrap. A better solution is to use optional.